# Make asynchronous http request in C

Tags: c, http, asynchronous, curl, pthreads

hi I'm a noobie with pthread and http requests in C, but I wanted to know if there is a way to make multiple asynchronous http calls in C, possibly at the same time. I ask "at the same time" because having a list of about 200-300 urls I wanted to parallelize requests by working on multiple threads (since asynchronous work on only one thread) passing sublists to threads and getting responses as fast as possible, avoiding bottleneck. I haven't found much for C looking on the internet, I only found curl_multi_* but i didn't quite understand how to use it. Thus I thought about writing something like this but it doesn't seem to solve the problem. Does anyone have any tips? or good tutorial for this stuff in C?

```
void *make_req(void *arguments) {
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    memory_t chunk;
    data_t * data = (data_t*)arguments;
    static int i = -1;

    chunk.response = malloc(1);
    chunk.size = 0;

    curl = curl_easy_init();

    while (i < data->nbr_sub_match) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        i++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 1<<23);
        // curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING, "gzip, deflate");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TCP_FASTOPEN, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, data->header);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, data->sub_match_urls[i]);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TCP_NODELAY, 1L);
        /* send all data to this function  */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, cb);
        /* we pass our 'chunk' struct to the callback function */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *)&chunk);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "libcurl-agent/1.0");
        /* get it! */
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        /* check for errors */
        if(res != CURLE_OK) {
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
        }
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        data->sub_match_json[data->response_counter++] = chunk.response;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    }
    /* cleanup curl stuff */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    i = -1;
    // return chunk.response;
    return NULL;
}

void start_threads(data_t *data) {
    int err, i = 0;
    pthread_t thread[data->nbr_threads];

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);


    if(pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL) != 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to initialize mutex: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    
    while (i < data->nbr_threads) {
        err = pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, make_req, (void *)data);
        if (err != 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: impossible make new thread %s\n", strerror(errno));
            exit(1);
        }
        i++;
    }
    // pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);
    
    while (--i >= 0) {
        pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);
    }

    curl_global_cleanup();
}
```

Comment: Use the [libcurl multi API](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-multi.html) you found. There are [example programs](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/multi-double.html) if the introduction and function documentation isn't enough.

Comment: it already knows how many requests it has to make by creating only 2 variables. but how can I use this program with tread ?

Comment: I don't know what tread is (threads?), but a dynamically sized array is your friend. No need for threads with curl multi.

Comment: use libevent and no threads